# CakePHP 2.1 Custom Pagination

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.1, sql-limit

I am using cakephp 2.1 and defined 3 tables as follows.

```
   `industries(id, name);`
   `movies(id, name, industry_id),` 
   `trailers(id, name, movie_id);`
```

I want to paginate the trailers for particular industry. So the code I have written is below:

```
  $this->paginate = array(
                    'Industry' => array(
                        'contain' => array(
                            'Movie' => array(
                               'order' => 'Movie.release DESC', 
                               'Trailer' => array(
                                  'conditions' => array(
                                       'Trailer.id !=' => $trailer_id
                                   )
                                )
                             )
                         ), 
                         'conditions' => array(
                             'Industry.id' => $id
                         )
                      )
                  );
```

If I would specify `'limit'` for `'Trailer'`, I get correct number of results but some `null` array for a movie which doesn't contain any trailers. Please help me to get the number of specified limit of trailers for particular industry. The work will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you've got your `contain` key in the wrong place. It should be defined before the models.

```
<?php
$this->paginate = array(
  'contain' => array(
    'Industry' => array(
      'Movie' => array(
        'order' => 'Movie.release DESC', 
        'Trailer' => array(
          'conditions' => array(
            'Trailer.id !=' => $trailer_id
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
    'conditions' => array(
      'Industry.id' => $id
  )
);
```